# In MIPS what should I return when the answer is null

Tags: mips, return-value, conventions

I have a MIPS function to find a character in a string. I'm not sure what to return if the character isn't in the string. In c++ I might return -1, but I'm not sure that's the correct convention in MIPS. Should I return 0? raise an error? something else?

```
# return the address of the first occurance of the character in a1 in the string at the address in a0
FIND:
move $t0,$a0    # t0 has address
LOOP:
lb $t1,0($t0)   # load current char into mem
beq $t1,$a1,END # check if the current char is the right one
beq $t1,$zero,FAIL # end of string
addi $t0,$t0,1  # move to next char
j LOOP
FAIL:
li $t0,-1  # return -1 as the address
END:
move $v0,$t0    # return
jr $ra
```

Comment: If the result is an address, return 0 (or some address that isn't valid on your target platform). If it's a bool, return 0. If it's a position, return a negative number.

Comment: Do the same in MIPS as you would in C/C++.  C/C++ functions should be able to call assembly and vice versa, and for that to work they have to follow the same logical function prototype including parameter and return value definitions.